# qt-creator no response after open project

Tags: ubuntu, qt-creator

I'm using parallels desktop on macbook air.
I install ubuntu 14.04.4, and install qt-creator 4.0.2 (qt 5.7.0).
After a clean installation, I opened qt-creator and new a project.
after project created, the whole qt-creator had no response.

If I click the "edit" tag on the left, qt-creator had no response.
But if I click the "welcome" tag (the first tag) on the left, qt-creator response well.
If I press "ctrl+R" to build and run the project, it goes well.

so I can new a project and build, and run, but I cannot see the code.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what happens when you click on the Edit pane?

Comment: You can see the code if you resize the window in order to force a repaint of QtCreator. Having the same problem...

Comment: A temporary workaround...try running Qt Creator with `/Path/To/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator -noload QmlDesigner -noload QmlProfiler`

Comment: @sashoalm just nothing happen, and stay on the welcome screen.

Comment: @luliu I resize the window, then I can see the code. But I cannot edit them. I have to : 1 click 2 resize 3 input code 4 resize bla bla bla. Every step has no response until I resize the window. I tried -noload QmlDesigner -noload QmlProfiler but nothing change.

Comment: @Iuliu,Oh, your name start with an up case i. maybe you haven't see my comment. I tried noload the two plugin but nothing change. and I try to install qt-creator 4.0.2 on : macbook air -> parallels desktop -> ubuntu 16.04.1, but fail again. qt-creator 4.0.0 goes well and real machine goes well.

Comment: @YuKunlin Sorry, I didn't check my StackOverflow account for some time...I had a similar problem once and loading Qt Creator w/o the qml designer and the qml profiler seemed to have fixed the problem although the 2 componets couldn't be used(the two components are messing with the OpenGL(I hope I'm not talking idiot things...)). As far as I read, there are some problems with Qt Creator and virtualization(IDK if this is the exact same thing that happens to you): https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53954